# How can I cancel a PayPal Billing Agreement via an API call

Tags: paypal, express-checkout, paypal-nvp

I'm using PayPal NVP API to do reference transactions with express checkout. I create billing agreements and charge using the agreements in sandbox and in a production environment, however when I try to call BAUpdate (`METHOD=BillingAgreementUpdate` in the NVP API) I get the a response with error code `81002` and description

> Method specified is not Supported

I can't find anywhere in PayPal's docs if this method is deprecated or if I need to send something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper call is [BillAgreementUpdate](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/#id104NF0G0G5Z) (confusing, I know). That should let you cancel your billing agreement.